# DVI vs HDMI graphics card output

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv, dvi, tuner-card

Asking on behalf of someone: I want to buy a new graphics card but do not know which would be best in terms of output, DVI or HDMI, the sound part of the HDMI is not really required, I just need something to go to my new 32 inch hd tv. It accepts both DVI and HDMI. I only need it for basic gaming but mostly as a media center to watch movies and tv shows on.
Also for windows media center's TV application, I need a tv card, should I get a graphics card with bult in tv card, or a usb dongle??

Comment: You've said that sound isn't important, but you need to think about that.  Why isn't it important and where will the sound be output?  If you're happy outputting to your computer speakers then that's ok, if you're expecting to use an audio cable to the TV alongside HDMI then that could be a problem.

Comment: Have a nice set of speakers I am happy with, so never expecting to use the TV's speakers, but I cansee your point

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The video signal is identical in DVI and HDMI.  In fact, you can buy cheap (under $5) to convert one to the other. So from a quality perspective, there is no difference.

HDMI cables seem slightly more convenient, with smaller connectors.  Also, if you plan on hooking it up to other TVs, they are more likely to have HDMI than DVI.  On the other hand, if you ever think you would use a computer monitor, it is more likely to have DVI than HDMI.

Comment: I agree with this, and want to add that many high-end monitors have HDMI inputs as well as DVI, so DVI isn't necessarily required for monitors, either. Make sure the output is HDMI 1.3 (or higher) or you may not have full resolution (though I don't know of any cards you can buy without 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

DVI does not include HDCP. This may or may not influence your choice of ports.

Comment: (In my case, I'd pick DVI.)

Comment: As an related example, my Xbox won't play DVDs through HDMI because of HDCP, but I can use a component cable to play them fine. I'd pick DVI whenever possible.

Comment: DVI can transport HDCP.  "HDCP is a specification developed by Intel Corporation to protect digital entertainment across the DVI/HDMI interface."  http://www.digital-cp.com/

Comment: DVI *can* but it is not *guaranteed* whereas HDMI *requires* it.